# can i apply gsettings without relogin?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, tray, ubuntu-unity

I want my program's icon in Unity system tray. I do `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel ...`, but I want the changes to be applied without relogin, is it possible?

Comment: I've just figured out that I can do following: `unity --replace`, but I don't know about side effects of it solution. Any suugests?

Comment: and i don't think `unity --replace` is a good solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so... i think there is no way....